# How do I get the number of sessions in which two items were consulted?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have got sessions table and  that contains

- session_id
- item_id
- timestamp

And I want an SQL query to get the following outcome:

item1, item2, nb_sessions_consulted_1_and_2

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a self-join and aggregation:

```
select t.item_id, t2.item_id, count(*)
from t join
     t t2
     on t.session_id = t2.session_id and t.item_id < t2.item_id
group by t.item_id, t2.item_id;
```

Comment: Why t.item_id < t2.item_id! I think they must be different, no?

Comment: @geek-tech . . . That is so each pair only shows up once in the results.  If you want paris in both directions, then remove it or replace it with `t.item_id <> t2.item_id`.